# filezilla not writing to log

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I am currently running FileZilla 3.15.0.2 (that version because of the bug that causes latest version to crash after any remote operation) on Ubuntu 16.04.

I am having quite a few issues with FileZilla not acting as I think it should.  The biggest of which is that I cannot seem to get it create a log file whatsoever.   I told it to create `/var/log/filezilla.log` and that file isn't there and even after I create it (in the hopes it will append) nothing.

My main problem is that remote directory listings are empty when connecting to an Azure ftp server.  But without the logs, I have no idea where to even begin this game of hide and seek.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Short of fixing this, recommendations for a better/working ftp client would be great too.  :)

Thanks in advance,
V

Comment: 3.15.0.2-1ubuntu1 is shipped with Xenial. Usually `/var/log` is writable only by root. But running FileZilla as root is bad idea. Change log-path to somewhere in your `/home` directory. You can force filezilla to be more verbose by clicking on log-part of window and selecting *Show detailed log* here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @N0rbert.  The detailed log in screen portion that shows logging tip worked.  But still unable to get FZ to write an actual log file anywhere.

And I can't understand why the remote file directory is always empty.  This only occurs on my laptop.  My main dev machine it works flawlessly.  I can't see any differences between the two setups.  Clearly something is different though.  :(